# How to import csv into powerquery from the box in proper format

Tags: dax, powerquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1YJW.png)

I am trying to import csv file into powerquery from box link, but getting incorrect format or even no data at all. The box link is working if its inserted directly to the browser - it download the csv file correctly, but its not working when trying to use the New Source-Other sources-web option. I tried all kinds of File origin, the default one is 65001: Unicode(UTF-8), but its giving me again wrong data as in the below screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ud0mV.png)

I tried all kinds of File origin, the default one is 65001: Unicode(UTF-8), but its giving me again wrong data as in the below screen:

Comment: your second image says the file is an html file   How do you know it is a csv file? Did you open the source file in notepad and look at what is in there

Comment: Hi, yes, its a csv. What is weird that the upload to power query doesnt work only if I am trying with the csv uploaded directly by database system i am using. But if I downloaed the csv from the box, and rename it and upload back to box - than the import into power query is working fine...I dont get the issue...

Comment: Sounds like an issue with source file, not with powerquery. Good luck

Comment: Some web apis will  return HTML pages when there are errors. It's possible your query string has the wrong format. Sometimes the HTML will have an error message. -- `utf-8` is the default format for web content. If it's a CSV, sometimes they will use `latin1`  or `ascii` instead. ( Actually 100% of `ascii` files are also  valid in `utf8` formats, by definition. The only time it wouldn't work, is when it wasn't really ascii to start with. ( like latin1 ))